# poi how to set different data types in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

New to Java and POI
Im using POI 3.15 with Java and i want to write from JTable to Excel. My JTable is very long (many rows) and  have different data types like numeric, string, blank and customized date format. How can i program in Java so that my data from JTable writes to Excel with the same data types when i click a button. I get an java.lang.NullPointerExeption error because i have a Blank cell that i most have Blank in Excel. 
`

```
btnFil.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser("c:\\test\\");
                save.setDialogTitle("Save as...");
                save.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xls", "xlsx", "xlsm"));
                int choose = save.showSaveDialog(null);

                if(choose == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    XSSFWorkbook faktura = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    XSSFSheet sheet1 = faktura.createSheet("Under 7m3");
                    try{
                        TableModel tableModel = under.getModel();

                        for(int i=0; i<tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            XSSFRow newRow = sheet1.createRow(i);
                            for(int j=0; j<tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                                XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell((short) j);

                                if(i==0){
                                    newCell.setCellValue(tableModel.getColumnName(j));
                                } else {
                                    newCell.setCellValue(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());


                                }
                            }
                        }

                        FileOutputStream otp = new FileOutputStream(save.getSelectedFile()+".xlsx");
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(otp);
                        faktura.write(bos);
                        bos.close();
                        otp.close();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filen ble lagret!");
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

`

[And here is an exemple of my JTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSMKd.jpg)